# How To Create Alarm Notification Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, alarm

I want to when user get notification from fcm (Firebase Cloud Messaging) or scheduler local notification like alarm notification like image below :

[image]

Here my code :

```
func onTest() {
      
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Weekly Staff Meeting"
        content.body = "Every Tuesday at 2pm"
        // Configure the recurring date.
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

        dateComponents.hour = 16    // 14:00 hours
        dateComponents.minute = 11
           
        // Create the trigger as a repeating event.
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
                 dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        
        // Create the request
        let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString,
                    content: content, trigger: trigger)

        // Schedule the request with the system.
        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
           if error != nil {
              // Handle any errors.
           }
        }
    }
```

My code right now just like the usual notification which disappears in 5 seconds I want to make it like an Alarm notification or Whatsapp Calling Notification. Please Help Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Apple's limitation, app dev can only play notification tone up to 30 seconds. It will play default notification tone if your tone is longer than 30 seconds.

If your notification tone is gone after 5 seconds, try to set your notification presentation options to list, badge and sound.
Once there's no banner for notification, your 30seconds tone will play till the end.

Unfortunately there's no legal way or any workaround to have notification ring continuously such as alarm clock. Hope I was wrong though.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationpresentationoptions

Answer (score 0):

What I think, max you can do is to present a local notification. But yes that would not be exactly like an Apple Alarm notification. In Reality, you don't have permission for this. You can only present the local notifications.

Comment: The problem is my notification I create just disappears on 5 seconds, which I want to make like an Alarm notification, which means the alarm will disappear when we click on that notification.

Comment: Both FCM or Local Notification it will disappear for 5-second bro.

Comment: But there is no other way. You cannot make local notifications to show permanently. However, your notification will be always there on the notification screen.

Comment: If want being permanent what should I do?.

Comment: Any link tutorial or keyword.

Comment: You can check EventkIt -> EKCalendarItem. There you can add alarms. But it will not show as your app notification. Rather it will show as a calendar Alarm.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/setting_an_alarm

Comment: have you try it and work? bc was not worked and the documentation apple is kinda terible